# Passing domain into Scrapy Web crawler

Tags: python, scrapy

I am building a web crawler which the user will enter the URL into a script that they run first, then said script runs crawler with the domain entered into it. I have some cleaning to do, however I need to get the protoype going. I have made the code and what happens is that the crawler script keeps asking for the URL. I have tried using the terminal commands to enter it however I don't think my code is compatible with that. Is there a better way to pass domains entered by an end users from another script?

```
# First script
import os

def userInput():
    user_input = raw_input("Please enter URL. Please do not include http://: ")
    os.system("scrapy runspider crawler_prod.py")

# Crawler Script

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

from run_first import userInput

userInput()

class InputSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = "Input"
        user_input = ""
        allowed_domains = [user_input]
        start_urls = ["http://" + user_input + "/"]

        # allow=() is used to match all links
        rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True, callback='parse_item')
        ]

        def parse_item(self, response):
            x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            filename = "output.txt"
            open(filename, 'ab').write(response.url + "\n")
```

I run it just by running the first script through the terminal. Some help figuring out how to pass a domain as a variable would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `start_requests` method instead of `start_urls`:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request(url=self.user_input)

...
```

Also remove the `allowed_domains` class variable so the spider can allow all domains it needs.

That way you can just call the spider with `scrapy crawl myspider -a user_input="http://example.com"`

Comment: Problem is that my goal is to make a crawler that only includes links on the domain and exclude domains outside the requested domain. Also I'm running this as a single crawler file instead of creating crawlers. 

I tried your solution and I'm getting `NameError: global name 'Request' is not defined` errors in the script.

Comment: @George `from scrapy import Request`. `start_requests` method needs to return some `Request` object to start off the crawl, by default it iterates through `start_urls` and yields a `Request` object for every url in the list.

Comment: @Granitosaurus Yes I didn't realise I needed that. I added that in and it started to work my only other issue is that I need the allowed domains in there to be able to restrict crawling urls for the same domain. So I still have to figure out how to pass variables from a separate script. Or figure something else out.